# h:selectoneradio validation error

Tags: jsf-2

Please, help me to tackle with next matter.
I have error "requestAccess:selectAccess: Validation Error: Value is not valid" when submit form.

```
<h:form id="requestAccess">
 <h:selectOneMenu id="orgList" value="#{requestAccessBean.currentOrg}">
<f:selectItem itemLabel="-- select --"   itemValue="null" />
<f:selectItems value="#{requestAccessBean.orgList}" />
<f:ajax event="change" execute="@this" render="selectAccess"/>
 </h:selectOneMenu>

<h:selectOneRadio id="selectAccess" valueChangeListener="#          {requestAccessBean.accessChanged}" value="#{requestAccessBean.currentAccess}" layout="pageDirection">
<f:selectItems value="#{requestAccessBean.accessList}" />
 </h:selectOneRadio>
</h:form>
```

```
@ManagedBean(name = "requestAccessBean")
public class RequestAccessSection {

private List<SelectItem> accessList;
private List<SelectItem> orgList;  
private String currentOrg,currentAccess;

public void accessChanged(ValueChangeEvent event) {
 this.currentAccess = event.getNewValue();  
}

 public List<SelectItem> getAccessList() {    
  if (this.accessList == null) {
   this.accessList = returnAccessList();
  }
  return this.accessList;
}

public List<SelectItem> getOrgList() {
 if (this.orgList == null) {
   this.orgList = returnOrgList();
 }
 return this.orgList;
}

public List<SelectItem> returnOrgList() {
  List<OrgUnit> orgList = new ArrayList<OrgUnit>();
  List<SelectItem> selectItemsOrgList = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
  orgList = getBusinessDelegate().getOfficeBranches();        
    for(OrgUnit org : orgList){
    selectItemsOrgList.add(new SelectItem(org.getGlobalid(), org.getOu()));
 }
 return selectItemsOrgList;
}

public List<SelectItem> returnAccessList() {
  List<String> accessList = new ArrayList<String>();
  List<SelectItem> selectItemsAccessList = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();    
  String userId = (String) getSessionMap().get(USER_ID_KEY);     
  accessList = getBusinessDelegate().getAccessList(userId, this.currentOrg);    
  if(accessList!=null){  
    for(String access : accessList){
      selectItemsAccessList.add(new SelectItem(access, access));
  }    
 }  
 return selectItemsAccessList; 
}

public String goToOrderAccessPage(){   
  return "orderaccess.jsf";
 } 
}
```

Previously, i have orgList and accessList of String type, and validation error still exists.
Could someone help me? Thanks in advance!

UPDATE:
I change type of currentAccess to SelectItem and add attribute immediate="true" to command button but valueChangeListener method is not called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *Validation Error: Value is not valid*

You will get this error when the submitted value does not match any of the available select items. In other words, the `<f:selectItems>` didn't return exactly the same items during the form submit as it did during the form display.

---

> *I change type of currentAccess to SelectItem*

This is wrong. It should be the same type as the **value** property of `SelectItem`.

---

> *and add attribute immediate="true" to command button but valueChangeListener method is not called.*

You don't need the `valueChangeListener` in this particular case. In the listener method you're just duplicating what JSF is already doing during update model values phase. Get rid of it. I have also the impression that you really don't need `immediate="true"` here. Remove it as well.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, BalusC! But i don't understand why submitted value and value in <f:selectItems> are different and how should i fix it? Thansk for comment about valueChangeListener !